# What does SharePoint "DisplayAuthor" refiner mean?

Tags: sharepoint, full-text-search, sharepoint-2013

When I use (author: {some name}) in the query, I get results where the {some name} is the Author or the editor.
The Author refiner also shows names of Authors or editors within the scope of the results.

I followed the managed property "DisplayAuthor" and could not see if it is bound to the internal name "Author" only.

How can I make sure I only get results for the original "Author" only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Author managed property, you will see the following crawled properties which are mapped to the managed property:
[image]

Here are the values the mapped properties correspond to:

**Author**: Author as picked up by the content processing component.

**MailFrom**: The people names from the from line of an email file.

**Mail:6** Author, MetadataAuthor

**Author**:  The people names associated with One Note files.

**Internal:3** Contains metadata associated with internal SharePoint objects

**Internal:105**: Contains metadata associated with internal SharePoint objects

**Office:8**:  ModifiedBy metadata

**Office:4**:  CreatedBy metadata

**MetadataExtractorAuthor**: The author extracted from the body of Word documents and PowerPoint presentations.

So, when you search using **Author** managed property, it also returns editors(ModifiedBy).

For your requirement, you can create a new managed property and map the crawled properties that you want to show into it. Then search using the new managed properties.

Comment: Thank you that explains a lot

Comment: if my reply helps you, you can accept it as an answer.